# HtmlTextWriter & MVC 3 Razor Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, htmltextwriter

This is probably a quick fix, but I am writing to a `HtmlTextWriter` in my `HtmlHelper` and no matter what I try it is encoding the HTML so the output shows the markup.

Helper:

```
protected override void WriteHtml(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteFullBeginTag("div");
            writer.WriteEndTag("div");

            base.WriteHtml(writer);
        }
```

and it will out put this to the page: `<div></div>`

**EDIT**

I am calling it in the view like this:

```
@Html.SAIF().Toolbar().Items(items => {
    items.Add().Action("Action");
    ... ...
})
```

**Edit #2**

OK, let's see if I can explain this a little better.

If I use ViewContext.Writer to write my helper to the stream, when using a syntax like this:

`@Html.MyHelper`

It outputs encoded HTML (e.g.) `<div>Test Div</div>` = Not correct

If I use a syntax like this:

`@{Html.MyHelper.Render();}`

It renders correctly, meaning that it actually inserts the div into the DOM instead of displaying it as a string.

Make sense?

Comment: Have you looked at `@Htmll.Raw()` ? `Raw()` basically creates a `HtmlString` which Razor doesn't escape.

Comment: How does your helper method look like? How are you calling it in the view? You haven't shown enough details in your question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I have updated my post with the code in the view.

Comment: Details still missing. How does the helper look like? What's `SAIF`? What's `Toolbar`? What's `Items`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I am using a framework for View Components I have developed that allow for Fluent configuration of the Html Helpers. Basically I have a static class that provides the `SAIF` Component Factory for the `HtmlHelper`. Then that `ComponentFactory` send back different types of Builders for different view components.

Comment: I don't really see how we can help without more details or an example that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Please see my second edit above.